# Overriding wagtail modeladmin templates in docker with windows and ubuntu

Tags: docker, wagtail

I'm follow this article to override modeladmin template:

templates/modeladmin/app-name/model-name/

[Overriding templates](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v2.16.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#overriding-templates)

It was overridded in windows 11 with docker, but not work in ubuntu.

I have no idea why have to use volumes to override modeladmin template and it was only work in windows?

It is also work in windows not use docker.

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.1-slim-buster

RUN useradd wagtail

EXPOSE 8088

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PORT=8088
RUN apt-get update --yes --quiet && apt-get install --yes --quiet --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    libmariadbclient-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install "gunicorn==20.0.4"

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app


RUN chown wagtail:wagtail /app

COPY --chown=wagtail:wagtail . /app

USER wagtail

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear  --no-post-process
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn web.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8088
    volumes:
      - ./project/templates:/app/project/templates
    ports:
      - '8088:8088'
```

Can you give me some pointers about how to override it in ubuntu? thanks.

Comment: There is nothing operating-system specific about the way templates are overridden. However, you do need to restart the Django server to ensure that it finds new template folders that weren't there previously - my guess is that you're missing this step in your workflow when working under Ubuntu.